# Most repeated values

Tags: matlab, neighbours

I know how to check an `8-neighbourhood` in `matlab` (i.e; nlfilter). But, I want to assign the value which is more repeated to the center value. So, say for instance that I have the following values in the 8-neighbourhood:

2-values = 56

3-values = 64

1-value = 70

1-value = 87

1-value = 65

In this case we would assign `64` to the center pixel.

How can we do that?

Thanks.

Comment: What about conflicts, i.e. two values are most repeated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want either the [`mode`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/mode.html) or the [`histc`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) function.

> M=mode(X) for vector X computes M as the sample mode, or most
>   frequently
>       occurring value in X.

Example with your data:

```
x = [56 56 64 64 64 70 87 65];
mode(x)

ans =

64
```

But this will only get you the most frequently occurring value.

If you want the count of each unique item in the array, you could do,

```
unqx = unique(x);

unqx =

56    64    65    70    87

valueCount = histc(x, unqx)

ans =

 2     3     1     1     1
```

You could then sort this and take the first `N` values

```
valueCount = sort(valueCount, 'descend');
% Use unqx(valueCount(1:N))
```

Comment: To keep in mind that: *"When there are multiple values occurring equally frequently, mode returns the smallest of those values"*

Comment: To count, `histc()` is a better option.